# How do I put the form fields into a list to be able to iterate through them?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jformattedtextfield

I want to iterate through this form's fields using an `ArrayList`, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is the image of the form:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
    private void btnTotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:


 double index=Double.parseDouble(txtIndexNou.getText())-      Double.parseDouble(txtIndexVechi.getText());
 txtIndexTotal.setText(Double.toString(index));
 txtCam1.setText(Double.toString(index));
 txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index *a)));

 double index1=Double.parseDouble(txtIndexNou2.getText())-Double.parseDouble(txtIndexVechi2.getText());
 txtIndexTotal.setText(Double.toString(index1));
 txtCam1.setText(Double.toString(index1));
 txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index1 *a))); 

 double index2=Double.parseDouble(txtIndexNou3.getText())-Double.parseDouble(txtIndexVechi3.getText());
 txtIndexTotal.setText(Double.toString(index2));
 txtCam1.setText(Double.toString(index2));
 txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index2 *a)));

 double index3=Double.parseDouble(txtIndexNou4.getText())-Double.parseDouble(txtIndexVechi4.getText());
 txtIndexTotal.setText(Double.toString(index3));
 txtCam1.setText(Double.toString(index3));
 txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index3 *a)));

 double index4=Double.parseDouble(txtIndexNou5.getText())-Double.parseDouble(txtIndexVechi5.getText());
 txtIndexTotal.setText(Double.toString(index4));
 txtCam1.setText(Double.toString(index4));
 txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index4 *a)));
}
```

Comment: You would need to change the code that creates the fields to do that. Can you add the creation code to your question as well?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well, the code it's generated by NetBeans automatically. I don't know if I'm allowed to post all the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**txtIndexNou** and **txtIndexVechi** which I assume are some kind of text input must be created with a loop and there reference stored in an ArrayList, then when you want to read back their values, just iterate through the list.

### **Edit 1**

To optimize code duplication, you can encapsulate your logic into a method.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how, can I do this? I'm quite new to ArrayList. I would have adopted a rs.next() to iterate through the fields and a Mysql test database, but I want to learn how to do it using ArrayList.

Comment: Well, ArrayList is just a basic collection, use it to store your text inputs when creating them, then when you need to access the values, make a foreach on the list. If you need more info about lists you should consider reading some java course.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a list. I believe what you want to do is reduce code duplication. All you need to do is to create a separate method to do all the staff you are duplicating:

```
public void doStuff(String input1, String input2){
double index=Double.parseDouble(input1)-Double.parseDouble(input2);
 txtIndexTotal.setText(Double.toString(index));
 txtCam1.setText(Double.toString(index));
 txtTotal1.setText(Double.toString((index*a)));
}
```

And then call it:

```
doStuff(txtIndexNou.getText(), txtIndexVechi.getText());
doStuff(txtIndexNou2.getText(), txtIndexVechi2.getText());
doStuff(txtIndexNou3.getText(), txtIndexVechi3.getText());
doStuff(txtIndexNou4.getText(), txtIndexVechi4.getText());
doStuff(txtIndexNou5.getText(), txtIndexVechi5.getText());
```

Comment: using a method is a good idea to reduce code duplication, but it does not permit to make a dynamic number of field

Comment: @Povilas Milgevičius. Thank's for the code, but I think I'll have to do what Steve MARION said.